# Get count of an IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#-4.0, iqueryable

Assume we have the following collection

```
 IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10 };
 var query = list.Skip(5).Take(4);
 SomeMethod(query.AsQueryable()); 
 .
 .
 .
 public void SomeMethod(IQueryable<T> query)
 {
      var collectionCount = ?????  // count should be 10 not 4.
      ...
 }
```

How can I get the count of the original collection (without applying Skip and Take sub-queries) of the query in the SomeMethod.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you could get the information (except maybe by doing some *hardcore* reflection stuff). It is simply not there anymore. It’s like you wanted to extract the original count from something like this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10 };
SomeMethod(list[3]);

public void SomeMethod(int number)
{
  var collectionCount = ?????  // count should be 10
  ...
}
```

I think you *might* be able to get the information if instead of `IQueryable`, you would pass `Expression`, however, even this case would not be simple.

**Added** per comments:

It is not as simple as you might think; I don’t even think it is possible *fully generally*. However, for some limited use cases it *might* work. I have quickly hacked a method which “removes” any `Skip` a `Take` applied to the query and returns the original count. Give it a try, YMMV:

```
public int CountOriginal<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var ex = query.Expression;
    while (ex.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
    {
        var call = (MethodCallExpression)ex;

        if (call.Method.Name != "Skip" && call.Method.Name != "Take") break;

        ex = call.Arguments[0];
    }
    var enumerable = Expression.Lambda(ex).Compile().DynamicInvoke(null) as IEnumerable<T>;
    if (enumerable == null) throw new NotImplementedException();
    return enumerable.Count();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, when you move an IQueryable around, you move a provider and an expression. So I think it is possible to execute a different query on that provider.

Comment: @Mohammadreza - In your example, you work on `IEnumerable`, only the _final_ enumerable gets converted to `IQueryable`. The Queryable gets created from IEnumerable containing [16, 17, 18, 19], no trace of the original list left.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. In my project, I use IQueryable<T> because I'm actually working with database using EF4. The above code is just a sample for my situation and the fact that I didn't know what you just said. So, is it still possible?

Comment: @Mohammadreza - answer amended

Comment: I getting is error "This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." at DyanmicInvoke point. I'm using EF4. Anyone experience this before?

Answer (score 0):

list.Count should return the count of the original list

Comment: I want to get the count in the SomeMethod(IQueryable<T>) method.