# Extract paging from IQueryable

Tags: c#-4.0, iqueryable

I'm using a function to allow query composition from Web UI and I would to implement paging functionality which it will be available for dataBound controls such as ObjectDataSource, gridView, etc:

```
  public class MyClass<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        FakeEntities xxx = new FakeEntities();

        public  IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> queryExpression)
        {
            var query = xxx.Set<TEntity>();

            return queryExpression(query).ToList();
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            // What Can I return?
        }
    }

// **** USAGE ****
  MyClass<User> u = new MyClass<User>();
            var all = u.Get(p => p.Where(z => z.Account == "Smith").OrderBy(order => order.IdOther).Skip(1).Take(2));
```

The above query use Take and Skip function, so can I get real count of my entities? Obviously I must return Query Count without modifying filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution: [Get count of an IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002164/get-count-of-an-iqueryablet)

However I get targetInvocationException with inner message **{"This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."}**

I know my request could be freak-abnormal, because best practice should to impose to move "presentation needs" to some wrap class and that's is what I'll do. So I don't need anymore to get Count entities on my business logic class.

That's just UI concern only.

Thank you the same.